# Petersen Riemannian geometry p86

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'm confused by a computation in Peter Petersen's Riemannian geometry book.

We consider $S^{2n+1}$ viewed as embedded in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}.$ The circle $S^1$ acts naturally on $S^{2n+1}$ by complex multiplication. We let $V$ be the unit vector field tangent to this action.  Then $\sqrt{-1}V$ is the inward unit normal vector field on $S^{2n+1} \subset C^{n+1}.$

Let $X,Y$ be vector fields on $S^{2n+1}.$ Petersen then claims:

$$g(Y, \sqrt{-1} \nabla_X^{\mathbb{C}^{n+1}} \sqrt{-1} V)=g(Y, \sqrt{-1}X),$$ where $g$ is the metric on $S^{2n+1}.$  Can anyone explain where this comes from?

[Note that I have omitted some information about this particular computation which seems irrelevant to my question.]

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$It's a general, easily-verified (see below) fact that if $W$ is the "identity vector field" $W(x) = x$ on a (real or complex) Cartesian space, then
$$
\nabla_{X} W = X\quad\text{for every vector field $X$.}
$$

> We have $W = x^{i}\dd_{i}$. If $X = X^{i} \dd_{i}$, then $\nabla_{X} W = X^{j} \dd_{j}(x^{i} \dd_{i}) = X^{j} (\dd_{j} x^{i}) \dd_{i} = X^{j} \delta_{j}^{i} \dd_{i} = X^{i} \dd_{i} = X$.

Since $\sqrt{-1}V = -W$, Petersen's claim follows at once.